# How To Extract elements from a list of objects and store in String array

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist, retrofit

I am trying to get a response from the server and show it in a spinner.My  Server returns a response that contains a JSON array. The JSON Array has two fields **question** and **q_id** I want to store both the data in a different string array and want to populate spinner with details from **question** and by using the index of the question selected from spinner I want to get the elements from **q_id** array and send to server

thank you.

## Server Response

```
 {
    "data": [ 
        {
            "q_id": "21",
            "question": "Flipkart VS Amazone which is better?"
        },
        {
            "q_id": "22",
            "question": "Test"
        },

    ],
    "status": true,
    "message": "Bank Ac created sucessfully"}
```

## Model For this response

```
 public class Question {

    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    private List<Datum> data = null;
    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    private Boolean status;
    @SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
    private String message;

    public List<Datum> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<Datum> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Boolean getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Boolean status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

}
```

## Datum Class

```
    public class Datum {

    @SerializedName("q_id")
    @Expose
    private String qId;
    @SerializedName("question")
    @Expose
    private String question;

    public String getQId() {
        return qId;
    }

    public void setQId(String qId) {
        this.qId = qId;
    }

    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public void setQuestion(String question) {
        this.question = question;
    }

}
```

## Call To Server

```
private void getQuestions() {
    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS).writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS).addInterceptor(interceptor).build();
    if (retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(CommonObjects.BASE_URL)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    getquestion Service = retrofit.create(getquestion.class);

    Call<Question> call = Service.post(id);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<Question>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Question> call, Response<Question> response) {
            if (!response.body().getStatus()) {
                message = response.body().getMessage();
                showMessage(message);
            } else {
                Question jsonResponse = response.body();
                message = response.body().getMessage();
                CommonObjects.q.setData(jsonResponse.getData());
                CommonObjects.q.setMessage(message);
                CommonObjects.q.setStatus(response.body().getStatus());
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Question> call, Throwable t) {
            // handle execution failures like no internet connectivity
            BusProvider.getInstance().post(new ErrorEvent(-2, t.getMessage()));
        }
    });

}
```

## Interface

```
    public interface getquestion {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("feedback_question")
    Call<Question> post(
            @Field("userid") String question
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use for each loop and fill data in your arraylist. Do something like this.

```
else {
    ArrayList<String> QidList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> QuestionList = new ArrayList<String>();
    Question jsonResponse = response.body();
    message = response.body().getMessage();
    CommonObjects.q.setData(jsonResponse.getData());
    CommonObjects.q.setMessage(message);
    CommonObjects.q.setStatus(response.body().getStatus());
    for (Datum data : jsonResponse.getData()) {
        if((!TextUtils.isEmpty(data.getQId())) && 
                      (!TextUtils.isEmpty(data.getQuestion()))){
             QidList.add(data.getQId());
             QuestionList.add(data.getQuestion());
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use org.json library to extract that JSON like this:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(serverResponse);
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
ArrayList<String> qids = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> questions = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++) {
   JSONObject item = jsonArray.get(i);
   qids.add(item.getString("q_id"));
   questions.add(item.getString("question"));
}
```

Comment: I am getting Response<Question>response from server

Answer (score 0):

Use this type of code for parsing Json array. For more examples

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
JSONArray data = jsonObj.getJSONArray("data");

Question question = new Question();
List<Datum> datumList = new ArrayList<Datum>();

          if (data != null) {
          for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
              try {
                    JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) data.get(i);
                    Datum datum = new Datum();
                    datum.setQId(data.getString("q_id"));
                    datum.setQuestion(data.getString("question"));
                    datumList.add(datum);                        

                 } catch (Exception e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }
              }
            }
      question.setData(datumList);
```

For more detail and [learn](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp)

Comment: new JSONArray(data) what does "data" signifies here